# Failed to send file via socket

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm working with some C++ socket examples. The client run and can connect to the server but can't send the file. I think there's a problem with the `send()` but I can't fix it.Edit: the error message is "connection reset by peer"

Any ideas are welcomed.

I use OpenSuSE with QT 4.7.4

Here's the send and receive function

```
void str_server(int sock)
{
    char buf[1025];
    const char* filename = "//home//romanov//Documents//HelloWorld-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_in_PATH__System__Release//ss.png";

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!file)
    {

        cerr<<"Can't open file for reading";
        return;
    }
    while (!feof(file))
    {
        int rval = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), file);//read value
        if (rval < 1)
        {

            cerr<<"Can't read from file";
            fclose(file);
            return;
        }

        int off = 0;
        do
        {
            int sent = send(sock, &buf[off], rval - off, 0);
            if (sent < 1)
            {
                // if the socket is non-blocking, then check
                // the socket error for WSAEWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN
                // (depending on platform) and if true then
                // use select() to wait for a small period of
                // time to see if the socket becomes writable
                // again before failing the transfer...

                cout<<"Can't write to socket";
                fclose(file);
                return;
            }

            off += sent;
        }
        while (off < rval);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

//===================

```
void RecvFile(int winsock)
{
    int rval;
    char buf[1025];
    FILE *file = fopen("//home//romanov//Documents//HelloWorld-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_in_PATH__System__Release//ss2.png", "wb");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Can't open file for writing");
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        rval = recv(winsock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        if (rval < 0)
        {
            // if the socket is non-blocking, then check
            // the socket error for WSAEWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN
            // (depending on platform) and if true then
            // use select() to wait for a small period of
            // time to see if the socket becomes readable
            // again before failing the transfer...

            printf("Can't read from socket");
            fclose(file);
            return;
        }

        if (rval == 0)
            break; //line 159

        int off = 0;
        do
        {
            int written = fwrite(&buf[off], 1, rval - off, file);
            if (written < 1)
            {
                printf("Can't write to file");
                fclose(file);
                return;
            }

            off += written;
        }
        while (off < rval);
    }  //line 175
    while (1);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: There is no need to double the '/' characters in your string. '\\' shows up on Windows because `\` is an escape character and in order to get a literal '\' you have to have two of them in a row.

Comment: How does it fail? Does it print out any messages? This is a case where you should be using `cerr` and not `cout` BTW.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. 

The output is "can't write from socket".  So I guess there's a problem with `send()`. I will edit the question now, my bad :(

Comment: What happens if you print out the error from `errno` as well?

Comment: It's always a good idea to print the error message along with the error. Meaning, instead of `cerr << "can't write\n"`, do something like `cerr << "write: " << strerror(errno) << '\n'`. This kind of output will give you much better clues as to what's going wrong with your program.

Comment: Thank guys, the error exactly is "connection reset by peer" . Will update the question now!

Comment: are you sending the file to a own program or an ftp/http server?

Comment: For now, I just use localhost to test both the client and the server.

Comment: What is the other side doing while you run this?

Comment: I will update the `recv()` function now!

Comment: Big thank to all you guys, I fixed it. I just call the wrong socket in the server code :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , the problem is my bad, [I read the wrong socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044872/unix-tcp-ip-read-transport-endpoint-is-not-connected-read-transport-endpoint) in the `recvFile()` , if you guys encounter the same problem, you should check it out.